# encoding/decoding H.264 streams with different parameters

Tags: video, h.264, rtp

When using H.264 in a point to point session (bidirectional) some kind of media negotiation has to be performed. But, could the two streams have different characteristics, such as different profiles/levels etc.? After all, encoder and decoder are independent and it makes sense for them to be able to deal with different parameter sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The h.264 metadata can be found in-band or out of band.
if you are using rtsp to receive the stream you can find the data in the rtsp negotiation (see [http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2326.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512333/how-to-fragment-h264-packets-in-rtp-compliant-with-rfc3984)).

You also need to parse the rtp packets and see if there is some more data there (see ["How to fragment H264 Packets in RTP compliant with RFC3984"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5512333/how-to-fragment-h264-packets-in-rtp-compliant-with-rfc3984).