# Streaming hevc video

Tags: stream, rtp, encoder, decoder, hevc

Please help me here.

I want to packetise and stream an HEVC encoded bitstream that resides on the server (e.g.Linux stream server) to a client machine( Linux) where the RTP headers will be removed and and the bitstream decoded to YUV using HEVC decoder.

The stages will includes:

- Encoding the raw YUV and obtain an HEVC bitstream ---Server
- packetise the bitstream/encapsulate using RTP----server
- RTP packets streaming over UDP
- Remove RTP and store --- client
- decode bitstream using HEVC decoder ---- client

At the moment, I have only encoded the videos.

I want to start by packetizing the bitstream from the encoding process.

I will be grateful if someone could help me with information on how to extract HEVC NAL units and packetize for streaming over a network.

Many thanks.

James

Comment: What have you done so far?  I'm not sure what you're asking for help with.  SO isn't for solving the whole problem for you.  It's more to help you when you have hit a snag.

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking at my post, I will like to start with packetization, please can you help me with information on how to  packetise an HEVC bitstream for transmission?

Comment: Not really answering your question but take a look at MPEG-DASH, This [blog-post](http://www.bitmovin.net/blog-details/mpeg-dash-conformance-versus-client-performance.html) links to the reference sw.

Comment: Also, have a look at RFC6184 and this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/a/5587187/297323